# Using inputted variables in multiple functions in C++

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++ from scratch last week and on my assignment I have to create a quadratic equation solver through a few files: assign1.cpp which contains my main(), funcs.cpp which contains every function, and a makefile. I'm having trouble pulling everything together.

I have to get the coefficients from a user and return them to a struct with three fields, and use their inputted information in a few functions to solve the equation.

My programming is all over the place, and I got most of the errors to go away with coeff input; in every function and input.variable_name_here for a, b, and c.

Also, he wants us to use parameters.

I'm hardly half way done with the program.

Here's what I've got:

```
//Program to solve quadratic equation

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//Structure for coefficients to be used
struct coeff {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
};

//Prototypes?
double readCoeffs(), equSolver(), discr(), outResults();

//Read coefficients from user
double readCoeffs() {

    coeff input;

    cout << "Enter coefficient a: ";
    cin >> input.a;
    cout << "Enter coefficient b: ";
    cin >> input.b;
    cout << "Enter coefficient c: ";
    cin >> input.c;

}

//Solve quadratic equation from user's input
double equSolver() {

    coeff input;

    /*
    need to somehow get the discrim variable from discr() to this function

    discr();
    */

    double solution1 = (pow(input.b, 2) + sqrt(discrim)) / (2 * input.a);
    double solution2 = (pow(input.b, 2) - sqrt(discrim)) / (2 * input.a);

}

//Solves discriminent of quadratic equation
double discr() {

    coeff input;

    double discrim = pow(input.b, 2) - (4 * input.a * input.c);

}

/*
//Display on the screen results of the calculation
outResults() {

    if (//root exists)
        cout << "Quadratic equation with the following coefficients: \n";
        cout << "a: " << value << "; b: " << value << "; c: " << value << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "has the following roots ";
        cout << "Root1: " << value << "; Root2: " << value << "\n" << endl;

    else
        cout << "Quadratic equation with the following coefficients: ";
        cout << "a: " << value << "; b: " << value << "; c: " << value << "\n" << endl;

}

*/
```

Comment: It might help if you could actually ask a question. Try to be as precise as possible, e.g., “the compiler complains that `discr` does not return a value, why does it not just pick the last value computed?” – you may be able to help yourself much faster than anyone else could, with a little training and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Your `readCoeffs()` function declares the object `input`. This means that input only exists within the function, so you can't use it elsewhere - it falls out of scope when the function finishes. Also, your function is declared with a `double` return-type, but doesn't return anything.

Consider taking an argument as a reference to a `coeff` struct, and declaring it as `void`?

```
void readCoeffs(coeff &input)
{
    cout << "enter...";
    cin >> input.a;
    cin >> input.b;
    cin >> input.c;
}
```

Then do the same for other functions (passing the struct), and declare your struct within your `main()` function.

Edit: Added an example of a function with a return.

```
double discr(coeff &input)
{
double discrim = pow(input.b, 2) - (4 * input.a * input.c);
return discrim;
}
```

Comment: When I try that it's saying the readCoeffs it's an incomplete type and is not allowed, the the coeff type name is not allowed, and that it expects a ) and a ;

Comment: Did you also change the prototype to void, and add the argument?

Comment: If void readCoeffs(); is the correct way to instantiate a prototype then yes. It says that the declaration is incompatible. I tried it without the prototype as well

Comment: You'd need `readCoeffs(coeffs &input);` as your prototype if you want to pass the argument too (Which you'll need to if you want to change the struct variables)

Comment: Although if you don't have the prototype for readCoeffs, provided your struct is defined before your function, and your function before you use it, that shouldn't matter...

Comment: @Auchindoun You're doing something wrong. [Show us an example of your new code](http://ideone.com)

Comment: @chrisb2244 Alright I got it to go through, I just typed it in wrong and didn't notice >.< But when I did that, every time I used input.variable_name, the word input is greyed out. Why's that?

Comment: @Auchindoun You didn't change the prototype to take a `coeff&`.

Comment: Greyed out? You mean in your ide/text editor? If so, it's just a colour scheme effect, I guess?

Comment: Yeah it is a color scheme but it means that it isn't being used anywhere. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: @Auchindoun Also, you're creating `coeff` objects name `input` in every function when they already take an object named `input`. Take out those variables.

Comment: You still have a couple of functions with non-`void` return types, but no `return` command. If you want the function to return a value, finish it with `return (value);`, where `value` is of the same type as the function. If it modifies the struct you're passing as an argument (via a reference), then you should declare the function as `void`. (e.g. your equSolver function claims it is of type `double` but doesn't return any value, so when you call it (not that this will compile), anything you assign it to will be confused!)

Comment: Sorry, I read back my last comment and apparently it's too late to edit it - but to be clear, modifying a referenced variable doesn't mean a function HAS to be a void function. I just meant that if the aim of the function is to only change the referenced variable, and it doesn't need to be equal to something (ie, you don't intend something like `double x; x = discr(input_variable);`), it should be void. In the case of `discr` you do want a return value.

Comment: @chrisb2244 Alright. Thank you all for the help. I really appreciate it. One more question however, how would I get the discrim that I created back into equSolver to use in the equation? He wants the discriminate in a seperate function so we can use a boolean indicator if the root exists, but I don't know how to call discrim to equSolver to use it

Comment: You could call `descrim` in your `main()` function and assign it to a variable which you passed to an `equSolver(coeff &input, double desc)` function, or you could make the descriminant a property of your struct and assign it there - something like (within `main()`) : `input.desc = descrim (input);` if you also added `double desc;` to your `struct coeff {...}` section.

Comment: I suppose in order to avoid strange circular arguments, you could also make `descr()` a function belonging to `struct coeff`, but maybe that's a bit more complicated than needed (if you're interested, google `this->` or ask for more details :) )

Comment: Hmm, alright. I'll take all of that into consideration!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resist so I rewrote and reorganized the code to solve the issue. This compiles and does what you ask. I also fixed the quadratic formula because it should be:

(-b +/- (b^2 - 4ac)) / 2a

and you had

(b^2 +/- (b^2 - 4ac)) / 2a

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//Structure for coefficients to be used
struct coeff {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double sol1;
    double sol2;
};

//Declarations
void readCoeffs(coeff &x);
void equSolver(coeff &x);
double discr(coeff x);
void outResults(coeff x);

//Read coefficients from user
void readCoeffs(coeff &input) {

    cout << "Enter coefficient a: ";
    cin >> input.a;
    cout << "Enter coefficient b: ";
    cin >> input.b;
    cout << "Enter coefficient c: ";
    cin >> input.c;

}

//Solve quadratic equation from user's input
void equSolver(coeff &input) {

    double solution1 = ((-1 * input.b) + sqrt(discr(input))) / (2 * input.a);
    double solution2 = ((-1 * input.b) - sqrt(discr(input))) / (2 * input.a);
    input.sol1 = solution1;
    input.sol2 = solution2;

}

//Solves discriminent of quadratic equation
double discr(coeff input) {

    double d;
    d = pow(input.b, 2) - (4 * input.a * input.c);
    return d;

}

void outResults(coeff input) {

      if( std::isnan(input.sol1) || std::isnan(input.sol2)) {
        cout << "Quadratic equation with the following coefficients could not be solved: \n";
        cout << "a: " << input.a << "; b: " << input.b << "; c: " << input.c << "\n" << endl;
      } else {
        cout << "Quadratic equation with the following coefficients: \n";
        cout << "a: " << input.a << "; b: " << input.b << "; c: " << input.c << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "has the following roots ";
        cout << "Root1: " << input.sol1 << "; Root2: " << input.sol2 << "\n" << endl;
      }


}

int main() {

 coeff Coeff;
 readCoeffs(Coeff);
 equSolver(Coeff);
 outResults(Coeff);

}
```

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at this. Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: Regarding something being 'off', perhaps problems occur if `descr` returns a negative number, since `equSolver` has no knowledge of complex numbers? (Although perhaps that's what your `isnan(...)` section handles?)

Comment: The formula was off, I fixed it now.